# setting up environment variables in Play! framework

Tags: java, scala, variables, environment, playframework-2.3

I am trying to get the Play! framework up and running. After I extracted Play! version 2.3.0 to `C:\Play` and adding that directory (`C:\Play`) to my path in 'Environment Variables' (separated form the other paths with a ;), I tried running it with the command "Play new foobar" and I keep getting the error "'Play' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have looked at a few possible fixes to this on here

[Configuration Variables in Play! Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216271/configuration-variables-in-play-framework)

[Setting an environment variable for play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930386/setting-an-environment-variable-for-play-framework)

[Adding an environment variable for the Play! Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579575/adding-an-environment-variable-for-the-play-framework)

(The third was the most similar but that solution is not working for me.)

Comment: Is Windows case-sensitive about executable names? What happens if you use `play` instead of `Play`?

Comment: I tired both "Play" and "play", neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

In Play 2.3+ `play` command is replaced by `activator`.

More details in **[What's new in Play 2.3](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23)** doc

Comment: I tried activator and that does not work either. I followed the short tutorial on the play homepage (http://playframework.com/), couldit be that what I've done so far is just wrong for play 2.3.0, and they haven't updated it?

Comment: Which tutorial exactly? I don't remember whole documentation

Comment: I just followed the video on the play homepage titles "Introduction to play framework for java developers"

Comment: As you can see on it, it's for Play 2.1 from 2.3 all you need is download the activator and use `activator ui` command - in case of problems read the errors in the terminal and then tell us what's wrong, without this we can only guess, and nobody wants to waste time for blind shooting.