# Cannot modify my index.scala.html file and cannot connect to localhost:9000 in Play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.3

I am new to play framework and have managed to make the activator work on the cmd of Windows. Now that I created my project in Eclipse, I can't modify my index.scala.html file as shown in a tutorial I am following. Any feedback or suggestion on how to manipulate those files will be appreciated, thanks!

Note: Does it has something to do with the fact that the page localhost:9000 does not open up for me?

Comment: The link to the tutorial might help and the step where you're stuck maybe too.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mST2YmQYgS8 at 3:12. I can't make the localhost page appear(later in the video) and I can't manipulate files like he does... even if I have the project created

Comment: did you created the application using the play console? have you tried following the steps found on the [Getting Started Section right hand side](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Tutorials)

Comment: Yes, I got to the create new application part. My app is created. If it helps, I started the activator UI command and it told me that it failed in downloading org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2!scala-compiler.jar

Comment: do you use some proxy?

Comment: yes, but I identified it and that is how I managed to get play on my computer

Comment: could it be that your facing the [same issues like the guy in here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24112599/3165552). i must admit that i just read about the "new" activator command right now o.O

Comment: Thanks this helps! But my main problem is that I have a project and can't see it on my localhost:9000

Comment: did you already [approached to this point](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/resources/manual/gettingStarted/images/consoleRun.png) where the activator states that the server is running and listening?

Comment: Yes! I am listening to the 0.0.0.0:9000. But then when I try to go, I get a network error! :( I think it has something to do with the proxy but I am 90% that I setted it up properly

Comment: What can you see in play console? Is application running ok? For network issues try wireshark.

Comment: Windows works better with 127.0.0.1:9000,  0:9000 is the Linux style

Comment: Vote my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows, and on any other system, your hosts file can be broken.
[http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

Using 127.0.0.1:9000 will work the same on any system.
While 0.0.0.0:9000, 0:9000 may work only on more advanced browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse may be missing the association between the html file type and the text editor.

1. Go to Preferences -> General -> Content Types
2. Select Text
3. Click Add
4. Then add *.html and *htm to the File Associations.
5. Click Ok

Now when double clicking on an html file in the Package Explorer, it should open an edit view.